# Parsing the output of find

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Apologies for the noob question. The below code returns

```
<img alt="Microsoft Xbox One X 1TB Fallout 76 Bundle, Black, CYV-00146" class="hover-zoom-hero-image" src="https://i5.wal.co/asr/9b579e20-a90a-4cac-9f87-7754ec2dbd8d_1.ff268553c4cffc6e64cb684bfbc9bd3e.jpeg-3628c2d42c0afc02fb2a9eae106edfe3eae67c4f-optim-450x450.jpg"/>
```

How do i get just the url from the output?

```
image = soup.find(class_="hover-zoom-hero-image")
print(image)


<img alt="Microsoft Xbox One X 1TB Fallout 76 Bundle, Black, CYV-00146" class="hover-zoom-hero-image" src="https://i5.wal.co/asr/9b579e20-a90a-4cac-9f87-7754ec2dbd8d_1.ff268553c4cffc6e64cb684bfbc9bd3e.jpeg-3628c2d42c0afc02fb2a9eae106edfe3eae67c4f-optim-450x450.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can treat the bs4 tag like a dictionary of key-value pairs of [attributes](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes) and values. `image['src']` will get you the url.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html="""
<img alt="Microsoft Xbox One X 1TB Fallout 76 Bundle, Black, CYV-00146" class="hover-zoom-hero-image" src="https://i5.wal.co/asr/9b579e20-a90a-4cac-9f87-7754ec2dbd8d_1.ff268553c4cffc6e64cb684bfbc9bd3e.jpeg-3628c2d42c0afc02fb2a9eae106edfe3eae67c4f-optim-450x450.jpg"/>
"""
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
image = soup.find(class_="hover-zoom-hero-image")
print(image['src'])
```

Output

```
https://i5.wal.co/asr/9b579e20-a90a-4cac-9f87-7754ec2dbd8d_1.ff268553c4cffc6e64cb684bfbc9bd3e.jpeg-3628c2d42c0afc02fb2a9eae106edfe3eae67c4f-optim-450x450.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use image.get('src').

Example usage:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

print(soup.prettify())
Here are some simple ways to navigate that data structure:

soup.title

soup.title.name

soup.title.string

soup.title.parent.name

soup.p

soup.p['class']

soup.a

soup.find_all('a')

soup.find(id="link3")
```